# File Output node not saving anti-aliasing (Blender internal)

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, antialiasing

I'm trying to use the Z Combine node in Blender Render (internal) to combine a person and a shirt - node setup depicted below. The problem I'm running into is that the image saved from the File Output node does not save the anti-aliasing (Full Sample), whereas if I go to the Image Editor and go Image->Save as Image when the Image Editor is viewing the Composite, the anti-aliasing saves properly. Zoomed in portions of each image attached.

[image: Image from File Output]
[image: Image saved from image editor viewing the Composite node]
[image: Blender Render internal node setup]

Comment: Either I don't understand what you are trying to achieve of your node setup seems convoluted and overly complicated. Why not just use an *Alpha Over* node?

Comment: I ended up hiring a contractor to help me with this render setup and an Alpha Over node is exactly what they chose to go with. Obviously doesn't explain the unexpected behavior but will hopefully solve my problem.